# What "it is of" means?

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

> Section 40(1) of the Supreme Court Act sets out the main criteria the Court considers when deciding whether to grant a party leave to appeal. Under this section, the SCC may grant leave if it is of the opinion that the case involves a matter of public importance, a significant legal question, or any other matter the Court believes warrants its attention.

> Under this section, the SCC may grant leave if it is of the opinion that the case involves....

what does "it is of..." mean? how to understand this type of grammar structure?

Comment: The proper way to ask this question is: What does "it is of" mean?

Answer (score 3):

The phrase should be parsed "it is" + "of the opinion".

"Of the opinion" means "holds the opinion", "has the opinion", or simply "believes".

"It", here, refers to the SCC as a body.

So it means:

"Under this section, the SCC may grant leave if it **believes** that the case involves...."